# SBO Layout bring random record in case of draft or unadded documents

Tags: crystal-reports, sapb1

I am having a layout which is working fine, except for one part.
If we use this layout to view or print any added document (AR Invoice) it will bring the right data and records.

But if the user clicks view or print before adding the document to the system, or if the document was saved as draft then a random record will come into the layout, in a very randomly way, meaning if I close the view and open it again another record different than the precious shown one will come.

What I am looking for is simple as I thought, if a user tried to view or print a document that is not added into system then show blank page.

Any idea?

Here is the query I am using in CR:

```
SELECT   ohem.[U_Employee_Code] as'Cashier',OUSR.USER_CODE, OUSR.U_NAME,OUDG.[Code],OUDG.Phone1,OUDG.Phone2, OINV.DocEntry,oinv.docnum,  OINV.DocType, OINV.DocStatus, OINV.InvntSttus, OINV.DocDate, OINV.DocDueDate, OINV.CardCode, nnm1.seriesname, 
         OINV.Address2, OINV.Printed, OINV.CardName, OINV.U_Address, OINV.NumAtCard, OINV.VatSum, OINV.DiscPrcnt, OINV.DiscSum, OINV.DocTotal, OINV.DocRate, OINV.u_deldate,
                      OINV.ReceiptNum, OINV.GroupNum, OINV.OwnerCode,OINV.JrnlMemo, OINV.VatPaid, OINV.Address2 AS Expr2, OINV.U_CUSTNAME1 as 'Customer Name' , OINV.U_PHONE1, OINV.ExepAmnt, OINV.ExepAmntSC, OINV.ExepAmntFC, OINV.VatDate,OINV.TotalExpns, 
                      OINV.PaidSum, OINV.OwnerCode, OINV.BillToOW, OINV.ShipToOW, OINV.RetInvoice, OINV.ReqName, OINV.Requester, INV1.ItemCode, INV1.Dscription, INV1.Quantity, inv1.PriceBefDi,
                      INV1.SubCatNum, INV1.ShipDate, INV1.Price, INV1.Currency, INV1.Rate, INV1.DiscPrcnt AS Expr1, INV1.LineTotal, INV1.OpenSum, INV1.VatPrcnt, INV1.PriceAfVAT, 
                      INV1.unitMsr, OINV.TaxDate, INV1.GTotal, OINV.Comments, OCTG.PymntGroup, OINV.LicTradNum, INV1.BaseDocNum, INV1.LineVat, OINV.WTSum, oinv.u_cancelled,
                      OCRN.CurrName, oslp.SlpName,OUDG.Phone1,OUDG.phone2,
        oinv.u_empid as'Sales man',OUDG.Phone1 as 'Branch Phone',OUDG.phone2 as 'Customer Support Phone',OINV.U_PHONE1 as 'Customer Phone',inv1.shipdate as 'Item Delivery Date',  OINV.TotalExpns AS 'FREIGHT CHARGES',OINV.U_Address as 'Customer Address',oinv.UpdateDate, OINV.DocEntry


FROM         OINV INNER JOIN
                      INV1 ON OINV.DocEntry = INV1.DocEntry INNER JOIN
                      OUSR ON OINV.UserSign = OUSR.USERID INNER JOIN
                      OCTG ON OINV.GroupNum = OCTG.GroupNum INNER JOIN
                      OCRN ON OINV.DocCur = OCRN.CurrCode inner join
                     oslp on oinv.SlpCode = oslp.SlpCode INNER JOIN
       OUDG ON OUSR.[DfltsGroup] = OUDG.[Code] inner join 
        nnm1 on OINV.series = nnm1.series LEFT JOIN 
                      OHEM on OUSR.[userId] = OHEM.[USERID]
          
                        where OINV.DocEntry = {?DocKey@}
```

Comment: "ring the write data"...?

Comment: @vwegert , Didn't understand what do you mean ?

Comment: That's what you wrote, and I don't understand either...

Comment: lol , typing Mistake , "bring the right data" , srry for that :)

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to use ObjectId  to determine if the source is system document or draft .  this is it

```
if  {?ObjectId@} =13
SELECT   ohem.[U_Employee_Code] as'Cashier',OUSR.USER_CODE, OUSR.U_NAME,OUDG.[Code],OUDG.Phone1,OUDG.Phone2, OINV.DocEntry,oinv.docnum,  OINV.DocType, OINV.DocStatus, OINV.InvntSttus, OINV.DocDate, OINV.DocDueDate, OINV.CardCode, nnm1.seriesname, 
         OINV.Address2, OINV.Printed, OINV.CardName, OINV.U_Address, OINV.NumAtCard, OINV.VatSum, OINV.DiscPrcnt, OINV.DiscSum, OINV.DocTotal, OINV.DocRate, OINV.u_deldate,
                      OINV.ReceiptNum, OINV.GroupNum, OINV.OwnerCode,OINV.JrnlMemo, OINV.VatPaid, OINV.Address2 AS Expr2, OINV.U_CUSTNAME1 as 'Customer Name' , OINV.U_PHONE1, OINV.ExepAmnt, OINV.ExepAmntSC, OINV.ExepAmntFC, OINV.VatDate,OINV.TotalExpns, 
                      OINV.PaidSum, OINV.OwnerCode, OINV.BillToOW, OINV.ShipToOW, OINV.RetInvoice, OINV.ReqName, OINV.Requester, INV1.ItemCode, INV1.Dscription, INV1.Quantity, inv1.PriceBefDi,
                      INV1.SubCatNum, INV1.ShipDate, INV1.Price, INV1.Currency, INV1.Rate, INV1.DiscPrcnt AS Expr1, INV1.LineTotal, INV1.OpenSum, INV1.VatPrcnt, INV1.PriceAfVAT, 
                      INV1.unitMsr, OINV.TaxDate, INV1.GTotal, OINV.Comments, OCTG.PymntGroup, OINV.LicTradNum, INV1.BaseDocNum, INV1.LineVat, OINV.WTSum, oinv.u_cancelled,
                      OCRN.CurrName, oslp.SlpName,OUDG.Phone1,OUDG.phone2,
        oinv.u_empid as'Sales man',OUDG.Phone1 as 'Branch Phone',OUDG.phone2 as 'Customer Support Phone',OINV.U_PHONE1 as 'Customer Phone',inv1.shipdate as 'Item Delivery Date',  OINV.TotalExpns AS 'FREIGHT CHARGES',OINV.U_Address as 'Customer Address',oinv.UpdateDate

FROM         OINV INNER JOIN
                      INV1 ON OINV.DocEntry = INV1.DocEntry INNER JOIN
                      OUSR ON OINV.UserSign = OUSR.USERID INNER JOIN
                      OCTG ON OINV.GroupNum = OCTG.GroupNum INNER JOIN
                      OCRN ON OINV.DocCur = OCRN.CurrCode inner join
                     oslp on oinv.SlpCode = oslp.SlpCode INNER JOIN
          OUDG ON OUSR.[DfltsGroup] = OUDG.[Code] inner join 
           nnm1 on OINV.series = nnm1.series LEFT JOIN 
                      OHEM on OUSR.[userId] = OHEM.[USERID]

                  where OINV.DocEntry = {?DocKey@}
else select ' '
```